# Issue in area in asp.net mvc 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, routes, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have a Asp.net MVC 2 application which is completed and now i have to add some new features in it so i have created an Area in it, So it doesn't interfere with my existing application. The issue is when i run a page contains in that Area all other navigation links which are on masterpage which contains a menu and some other links stop working, when i saw href attributes if these links they are blank. I know this issue can be because of routing but i want to know that now i have soo many links defined without areas is it possible that they all work without area defined in their links and my new pages which are in this area folder works with area in their links?

I have defined AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas() in Global.asax and in Area i have override RegisterArea and define Areas specifc routes there.

Comment: If you don't like areas and want to forget about routing issues check out http://mvccoderouting.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting area="" for the route args argument when you are buliding up the links on you master page.

e.g.

```
Html.RenderAction("myAction", "myController", new { area = ""});
```

Comment: I explain in my question that i don't want to change all the previous links. Is there any way those link still works without specifying area?

Comment: If you don't explicitly specify the area ="" then my understanding is it will take the area from your current location and use that when building the link.  So, I think explicitly settign area="" is necessary.  From your question you mention all your links to change are in the master and some other links.  To me that does not sound like a big change to add area="" to the master page.  Someone else might have a better suggestion though.